# Flexbox center overflow columns next to each other

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create 3 columns but if the number of columns isn't a multiple of 3 I want the overflow/reminder columns to be centered instead of aligned left.

I sort of have it working apart from the remainder 2 columns floating under the first 3 are centered relative to the `div.hold` rather than the rows above.

An example if it was fixed 5 columns;

```
.col-md-4
.col-md-4
.col-md-4
.col-md-4 .offset-md-2
.col-md-4 .offset-md-2
```

Here is what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/m16yctyd/5/

```css
.hold {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #ccc;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  width: 33.333%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 30px auto;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  background: red;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  background: yellow;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  background: green;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  background: blue;
}

li:nth-child(5) {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="hold">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In case you are using Bootstrap 4, please refer to [this conversation on Github](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20321) It is about making the `.card-deck` responsive, you might be able to use it in your case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `justify-content: center` but you also need to remove `margin` left and right from flex-items.

```css
.hold {
  margin: 0px auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
li {
  flex: 0 0 33%;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px 0;
}
li:nth-child(1) {background: red}
li:nth-child(2) {background: yellow}
li:nth-child(3) {background: green}
li:nth-child(4) {background: blue}
li:nth-child(5) {background: orange
```

```html
<div class="hold">
  <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Aha, bingo thank you! Ofoucrse flex is centering the items so I don't need the ```auto``` margin. Thanks